# MySQL fetch results, sum it up

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to sum up values from one record (A) then add it to the sum values from another record (B), am wondering if this is possible?

```
ID    ValueA   ValueB   ValueC
1       5        5        5
2       1        2        3
3       6        3        3
```

So what i'm trying to do here is to take ValueA, ValueB and ValueC of each record, adds it up so i can make an average.

So for 
ID 1, i'll have 15 divide by 3 = 5

ID 2 i'll have 6 divide by 3 = 2

ID 3 i'll have 12 divide by 3 = 4

then i will have to add all 3 of these up
i'll get 11
and divide it by 3 and get an average of 3.67.

My Query

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM teams WHERE UPPER(team)=UPPER("'.$team.'")');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$ValueA = $row['ValueA'];
$ValueB = $row['ValueB'];
$ValueC = $row['ValueC'];
$All = $ValueA + $ValueB + $ValueC;
}
```

I know how to get the sum of 1 record, but not sure how can i do it with all 3 records. any help?

Edit : Sorry i forgot to add that i'll have to do average on each record first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(valueA + valueB + valueC)
FROM teams
```

should do the trick. Since you're selecting all records from the table, there's on grouping required.

Note that by default MySQL uses case-insensitive collations on tables, so your `UPPER(team)` business might not be required - removing the function calls would allow indexes (if any) to be applied to that particular match.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i just updated my post, i forgot that i have to do average on each record first before doing average on the sum of each records.

Comment: And divide that by 3 to get the result of all columns (what OP has as 3.67).

Comment: `AVG((valueA + valueB + valueC) / 3)` in that case.

Comment: but it has to be the sum of each record and then divide by the number of records it has?

Comment: average will automatically do "sum of all records, divided by number of rows". so in your case, with 3 rows, it'd be `(row1 + row2 + row3) / 3`

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know there is AVG in MySQL, :)

Answer (score 0):

[You can](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) sum SQL functions together:

```
SELECT
    (sum(ValueA) + sum(ValueB) + sum(ValueC)) / 3 as average
FROM
    <your table>
WHERE
    <your conditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(ValueA + ValueB + ValueC) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teams)
FROM Teams
```

That will you the average you are looking for.

Comment: You don't want two selects for this. You can either divide by another aggregation (`count(*)`) or do as Marc B did and use AVG.

Comment: Yes, forgot about AVG for a second, I upvoted his question. Thanks.